# List of Oldest Tafseer-e Quran available on Internet

Tags: quran, tafseer

I am looking for a list of Oldest [at least 500 years older] Tafseer-al Qur'an for some reason available online[in English] which meet the following criteria.

1. The authenticity is beyond question among *all Muslims*.
2. They are preserved in their original writing
3. Rich in detail

Comment: Tafseer Tabari is one of the oldest and the most complete Tafseers of the holy Qur’an. http://wikifeqh.ir/%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%B1_%D8%B7%D8%A8%D8%B1%DB%8C

Comment: I don't think you'll ever find any Tafsir fully translated into English, that's a really hard work for any group of translators to do, since most tafirs include things about the Arabic language that can never be explained in English.

Comment: I have answered the substance of your question below. As for the first two of your specific questions: No tafsir is recognised by ALL Muslims. And if "original writing" means "the author's autograph" then of course no early Islamic sources are preserved in the author's own hand. We know them only from later copies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Shoaib: altafsir.com is an excellent site. It contains the full text of lots of different tafsirs (in Arabic), beginning with the oldest and most famous: those of Tabari and Zamakhshari.

The first volume only of Tabari's book has been translated into English: 
http://www.scribd.com/doc/237275012/Tafsir-at-Tabari-Vol-1#scribd

This is only a small part of the work, but it will give you an idea of what it is like.

Otherwise, what can I say except that you should learn Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

i have seen one more site except altafsir com : http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/bookslist.php?subject=%CA%DD%D3%ED%D1%20%C7%E1%DE%D1%C2%E4

Comment: The question is about English sources!